# How to create a user account with specific permissions?

Tags: users, privileges

I want to create a unix user account with specific permissions: this user must be able to install software, but can't remove software. Furthermore, when the user logs in, root must receive a notification in the mail. It is possible?

I'm running Debian.

Comment: Is this user supposed to be able to run more commands, or only the ones you reference?

Comment: Other permissions just like normal user.

Comment: Can you just add a `sudo` rule? Also, why email notification? isn't `/var/log/{auth,secure}` enough?

Comment: I have, debian without sudo, so what now?

Comment: apt-get install [sudo](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/sudo)

Comment: lol i know it, but what if i cant install sudo

Comment: If you don't have `root` access, I see this fate very difficult...

Comment: You want to create a new user who can install but not delete software and you want to do that without root access to the machine? That won't be possible, plus, if a user can install, he can uninstall. Both operations involve write/execute access. Can't have one without the other.

Comment: @terdon not necessarily, provided it is done at the right level: if you enable the user to do `sudo package-manager install` only (instead of just the general `sudo package-manager`) and package-manager behaves reasonably, then it could work.

Comment: @peterph huh, interesting, of course that assumes that software is always installed via the package manager but I wonder if that would work. Can `sudoers` take directives like that? I would have thought you can only designate an _executable_ as runnable not the options passed to it.

Comment: @terdon yes, if you specify the command in `sudoers` with additional arguments (wildcards allowed), the rule only applies to invocations with exactly those (and not with any others) - see section `Wildcards` of `sudoers(5)`. As for the package management - only what is allowed can be run -- even if you tried to unwrap the package manually (or at some lower level), you'd need to have that enabled in `sudoers` (or in the PolicyKit configuration for that matter, since that's the privilege escalation framework used on desktops these days).

Comment: @peterph sounds cool, why don't you make that into an answer?

Comment: @terdon might as well... :)

Answer (score 2):

As for restricting the management privileges to just installing software, you can use sudo: you only allow the user to run the package management tools that do installing. Roughly you need somethin like this in /etc/sudoers:

```
Cmnd_Alias SWINST = /path/to/pkg-manager install_action *

power_user hostname= NOPASSWD: SWINST
```

This allows `power_user` on computer `hostname` to run the `/path/to/pkg-manager` with first argument `install_action` and arbitrary additional arguments, without being asked for password (for example for Debian this would translate to `/path/to/apt-get install *`, for SUSE based distributions `/path/to/zypper in *`).

There are two things to keep in mind:

1. The package manager has to be well-behaved in the sense that it must not allow several **actions** to be passed to it on one command line (e.g. `pkg-manager install foo, remove bar` would completely break it). Since package managers also handle conflicts even just installation may result in removal of software, use switch/configuration that disables this if possible (and see Craig's comment below).
2. You must not allow access to low-level package maintenance commands, that can install package from a local file. That would allow the user to prepare a privilege escalation package, install it and then you could wave your system good-bye. Instead you have to make sure that it will only be possible to install trusted software with the command.

For desktop systems, PolicyKit infrastructure is often used these days, so that would be another option.

Comment: Note that apt-get will sometimes automatically remove packages - e.g. due to Conflicts.  This could be exploited to remove some packages by careful selection of packages to install.  It would be safer to write a wrapper script around apt-get that sanity-checks the args, uses apt-get's `--no-remove` option, and maybe has a custom apt.conf file to override defaults.  use sudo to allow the user access to that script only.

Comment: @CraigSanders exactly my point, I'll put it more explicitly into the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possible, in last option of each line of `/etc/passwd`, you specify shell for each user. You can write a wrapper and instead of the default shell such as `bash` or `csh`, use your wrapper (probably a shell script).

You change the default:

```
mohsen:x:1000:1000:Mohsen Pahlevanzadeh,,,:/home/mohsen:/bin/bash
```

to:

```
mohsen:x:1000:1000:Mohsen Pahlevanzadeh,,,:/home/mohsen:/yourpath/yourshell.sh
```

You should then put two things in `yourshell.sh`:

1. command for mailing to root (`mail`, `mutt command` ... - read manual)
2. spawn the login shell `exec /bin/bash -l`

Comment: How will that allow a user to install but not remove software?

Comment: also that shell will not allow, because only valid shell list is `cat /etc/shell`

Comment: While this can lead to a solution, it's missing far too many steps to be usable. `/yourpath/yourshell.sh` needs to be added to `/etc/shell`, and you need to provide its content in your answer. Take care about what happens if the user presses `Ctrl+C` during its execution. Also, this doesn't solve the part about installing software.

Comment: user can write an `python script` instead of `shell` and define `CTR+C`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on a solution:

The semi-privileged user runs a script called 'please-install.sh'.  the script's arguments are package or program names.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<__EOF__ | mail -s "please install" root@localhost 

When you get time, please install these programs for me:

  $@

Thanks,

__EOF__
```

This has the advantage of a highly-sophisticated neural network specifically trained in the problem domain (and with millions of years of evolution in problem-solving tasks) to evaluate all security and other practical implications and react to each request with the decisiveness and speed that it deserves.  for example: "no, i'm not going to install that bit-torrent client on our production web server".

If you want to get fancy, you could use getopt to allow the user to specify priority options like -l or --low, -h or --high, -u or --urgent.